# the value of the variable doesnt change when i add something

Tags: javascript

the defaultMoney value change when I add money but When I add money again it just changes the value of the defaultMoney and doesnt add to value of it

here is the code

```
function addmoney(){
var defaultMoney=0;
var newMoney=document.form.newMoney.value;

defaultMoney+=newMoney

document.getElementById("money").innerHTML="defaultMoney";
}
```

Comment: `"defaultMoney"` is string. `defaultMoney` is variable

Comment: you need to assign the 0 value to defaultMoney outside that function in order to achieve what you want... As it is, every time you enter the function, it resets defaultMoney's value to 0

Comment: Create a snippet with your attempt.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyPjYr

Comment: Kindly see https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wyPjYr I added `parseInt()` to convert the input string to number

Answer (score 0):

You need

- a global variable to keep the money,
- a conversion to number and a check with a default value for the input,
- an update of the output with the result of calculation.

```js
function addmoney() {
    var newMoney = document.form.newMoney.value;
    defaultMoney += +newMoney || 0; // prevent NaN
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = defaultMoney;
    document.form.newMoney.value = '';
}   

var defaultMoney = 0; // global
```

```html
<div id="money">0</div>
<form name="form">
    <input type="text" name="newMoney" onchange="addmoney()">
</form>
```

Comment: @jlallas384 "still doesnt work" doesnt really help us to help you. Create a snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Every time your function runs, `defaultMoney` becomes `0`.

```
// declare default money outside of your function
var defaultMoney = 0;
function addmoney(){
  //Get your form by ID
  var newMoney = parseInt(document.getElementById("form-id").value, 10);
  // add the value
  defaultMoney += newMoney
  // append result - use variable name, not string
  document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = defaultMoney;
}
```

Comment: the problem inow is when i enter a value "10" it show 10 and when i enter the value "20" , it now show "1020"

Comment: It concatenated strings. You have to parse strings into number, check updated answer